# Update a column in SQL database using Python, sqlite3 and a list

Tags: python, sqlite

I have looked at other questions similar to this but some are ambiguous with little explanation of the answer. 
What I have is a sql database with 6 tables containing n number of columns.  I want to update, not insert, a column in one of the tables with data from a python list. This is a list called gbufids and consists of integers, but each entry is not contained in Tuples i.e [0,1,2,3] not [(1,), (2,), (3,)].
The table name I want to change is called Versions and the column is called ObjectID. I tried various ways I found, but none did the job in the way it needed to be done. I used the following, which I believe should convert each item in the list to a tuple before updating the column (ObjectID) in the table (Versions): **cur.executemany('UPDATE Versions set ObjectID=?', ((val,) for val in gbufids))**

This is followed by a commit and a close. I have  read that I need a WHERE clause if I am using UPDATE, but I was a bit confused about row. To me, a row is all cells in a row, but this is probably not what is meant. If anyone can provide an answer that is specific to my db, tables and column, it will be appreciated

Comment: SQL tables are unordered. How should the rows be identified?

Comment: Well, as stated, I have a named column in a named table that I want to populate from the first cell in the named column to the last cell in the named column with each entry in the given list. Can you tell me how to achieve that with the info given in the original post? If you feel I have omitted something, its probably because I am unsure about it and could do with some help or explanation. Thanks

Comment: Show some example data. Which list entry goes into which table row?

Answer (score 1):

An `UPDATE` statement without a `WHERE` clause will cause *all* rows of the table to be updated with *each* value you pass into the `executemany`, meaning you'll end up with all rows populated with the last value you passed. In order to match each value with a particular row, you'll need some way to tell the database which row you want to replace in each run of the statement. If you're sure the length of your list of updated values is equal to the number of rows in the table, and the order of your list is the same as the order of the rows you'd get with a simple `SELECT * FROM table`, then the easiest way would be to get the list of `rowid`s in the table:

```
rowids = [row[0] for row in cur.execute('SELECT rowid FROM Versions')]
```

Then you can pair up `rowids` and `gbufids` and pass that to your `executemany`:

```
cur.executemany('UPDATE Versions SET ObjectID=? WHERE rowid=?', zip(gbufids, rowids))
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I have a version of my code that does what I need. I could not post it though as a new question or as a comment. I would like to share what I have so others can use it.

Comment: @EMJAY There's nothing wrong with posting an answer to your own question. Just post it as an answer like you would if it was someone else's question.

Comment: I tried but I think I may have a block on answers due to previous answers I added when I was first on here. They are haunting me. Apparently though, I can edit previious answers so the system will recognise them as valid. Once I have done that, I will update this answer.